# what is azure number of running containers?

Tags: azure, hive, azure-hdinsight

i have created HDinsight cluster with 4 nodes. when i give the command "yarn node -list", it shows:

```
Node-Id          Node-State Node-Http-Address  Number-of-Running-Containers
10.x.x.x:xxxxx     RUNNING 10.x.x.x:xxxxx             0
10.x.x.x:xxxxx     RUNNING 10.x.x.x:xxxxx             0 
10.x.x.x:xxxxx     RUNNING 10.x.x.x:xxxxx             0
10.x.x.x:xxxxx     RUNNING 10.x.x.x:xxxxx             0
```

after i submit hive job, it calculates the mappers(ex:900) and reducers(ex:100). then if i check node details it shows the running containers with value 8 in all nodes. if i submit simple job, containers have value 2 or 1 randomly assigned to any of the worker nodes.

```
   1. we know that, the mapper/reducer job are assigned to worker nodes. here, is it 4 worker nodes are processing the work or containers are processing?
   2. basically, what is number of containers. 
   3. how the value of running containers assigned/changed?
```

Comment: finally, found the solution. the number of running containers shows the value of the disks from the node size. for example, if we are selecting the D4 V2 size with 3 worker nodes, then the number of running containers value would be 48. the calculation is (no of worker node)*(D4 V2 disks size i.e 16).

Answer (score 0):

During the creation of a hadoop cluster in azure HDinsight you will be configuring a storage account and a container in that storage account. The blob container is used as the default storage location by the cluster. Optionally, you can specify additional Azure Storage accounts (linked storage) that the cluster can access. The cluster can also access any blob containers that are configured with full public read access or public read access for blobs only.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-provision-linux-clusters